# Checking password requirements from .txt file

Tags: python

I am making a function which checks the passwords from a .txt file against some requirements like:

- '>8 characters
- has at least 1 uppercase letter
- has at least 1 number
- has at least special symbol (ex.@#&)

The .txt file looks like this: 
jank Ad5Xaingi2 
wincenty aerae)V9
asia19 Ahch&ah9
cichy Aoquu0GohC
frisbee bee;Ph8
alojzy01 Chae>v7
ziemniak Du4jee`g

where the first part is a username and after the space, password.

I don't know how to just check the password and leave out the username.

What i tried but I'm getting a type error: 
hasla is the list of the imported passwords file

```
import re
for i in hasla:
  while True:
    if(len(i)<8):
      print("False")
      break
    elif(hasla[i].isdigit()==True):
      print('False')
      break
    elif(hasla[i].isupper()==True):
      print('False')
      break
    elif(hasla[i].isalnum()==True):
      print('False')
      break
    else:
      print('True')
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: editing my answer to fit your code rn

Answer (score 0):

Since your usernames and passwords are separated by a space, you can use Python's .split() function to convert the string on each line into an array, then access the second element as your password.

If `hasla` is your textfile source, and `i` is a line in that textfile, then:

```
for i in hasla:
  psswd = i.split()[1] # for the rest of your code, reference "psswd" instead of "i" as this contains that line's password.

  while True:
    # rest of your password checking logic here
```

By default, .split() will split by whitespace, so for your case, no additional parameters are needed. `i.split()` will split the line and return an array containing the username in the first index and and password in the second. You then access the password at the second index with `i.split()[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which prints True if passwords satisfy mentioned conditions in question.
Although you need to note that it is **dangerous to accept `><;()` etc characters in input** if it's part of a web app. If you want to include them then **add such special characters in regex string** from below code.

```
import sys
import os
import re

def main():
   filepath = "a.txt"
   if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
       print("File path {} does not exist. Exiting...".format(filepath))
       sys.exit()
  
   bag_of_words = {}
   with open(filepath) as fp:
       for line in fp:
           validation = verify_specifications(line.strip().split(' ')[1])
           print(line,"validation",validation)

def verify_specifications(password):
  if password != '':
    if re.fullmatch(r'[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{8,}', password):
      # match
      return True
    else:
      #nomatch
      return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code **prints True if valid password and False if invalid password** along with line from text file.
**Output**

```
jank Ad5Xaingi2
 validation True
wincenty aerae)V9
 validation False
asia19 Ahch&ah9
 validation True
cichy Aoquu0GohC
 validation True
frisbee bee;Ph8
 validation False
alojzy01 Chae>v7
 validation False
ziemniak Du4jee`g validation False
[Finished in 1.2s]
```